# generic binary search in c++

Tags: c++, templates, search, binary

I'd like to write a template binary search algorithm, which can search a template type element in a template type QList using an arbitary comparator, like this:

```
template<typename T,typename compare_less>
static int binary_search(QList<T>* list, T target) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = list->count()-1;
    while (low <= high) {
        int middle = low + (high - low)/2;
        if (compare_less(*target, *list[middle]))
            high = middle - 1;
        else if (compare_less(*list[middle],*target))
            low = middle + 1;
        else
            return middle;
    }
    return low;
```

}

Now how can I implement this correctly in order to make it work with QDateTime* template parameters? I'd like to call the function like this:

```
int index = binary_search<QDateTime*, ???>(dateTimeList,date);
```

Where dateTimeList is of type QList, date is of type QDateTime* and I really don't have any clue what to write in the place of question marks.

Can someone help me implement the algorithm correctly and show me how to call the algorithm with these arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have to implement anything, if the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlist.html) is valid. Just use std::binary_search with your list's .begin() and .end(), and if you need to implement a comparator, do so and pass it to the STL algorithm.

Comment: The problem is afaik, that std::binary_search returns -1, if no element found, but I'd like to return the index, where the element should be inserted into.

Comment: So use std::lower_bound (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/). You may need to add a test for equality if you don't want to insert duplicates, but it will give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now I tried to use the std::lower_bound, but the compiler complains, that lower_bound is not a member of std. I included 'using namespace std;' at the beggining. What could be the problem?

Comment: Thanks, Thats the solution, I looked for.