# passing string to template function

Tags: c++, string, templates

I use template to do generic binary search, but in string case I cannot get the result. I cannot get only string type result.
please help me out to understand Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T binarySearch(T arr[], int left, int right, T x)
{
     if(right >= 1)
    {
        int mid = (left + right)/2;
        if(x == arr[mid])
        {
            return mid;
        }
        //right side of array
        else if(x > arr[mid])
        {
            return binarySearch(arr,mid+1,right,x);
        }
        //left side of array
        else
        {
            return binarySearch(arr,left,mid-1,x);
        }
    }
    else
        return -1;
}

int main()
{
     int intArr[11] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
     double doubleArr[11] = {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0};
     string stringArr[11] = {"abc", "bcd", "cde", "def", "efg", "fgh", "ghi", "hij", "ijk", "jkl", "klm"};
     int length = sizeof(intArr)/sizeof(intArr[0]);
     cout << "binarySearch<int>(intArr,0,length,9): " << binarySearch<int>(intArr,0,length,9) << endl;
     cout << "binarySearch<double>(doubleArr,0,length,1.3): " << binarySearch<double>(doubleArr,0,length,1.3) << endl;
     string s = "cdf";
     cout << "binarySearch<string>(stringArr,length,cdf): " << binarySearch<string>(stringArr,0,length,s) << endl;
}
```

Comment: The actual error message you get should contain more information. From it, it should not be to hard to find out you're not providing enough arguments to the function. Compare the `binarySearch<string>(...)` call to the other calls you've made.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generic binary search in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844200/generic-binary-search-in-c)

Comment: And don't update your question with the fixed code! It will make comments and answers useless, and your question as well since the problem no longer exist.

Comment: And please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for helping me! But I still want some help.

Comment: If you wanted help with some other unrelated issue, then please ask a new question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't know why I cannot get the result for string type. Could you help me? If I did not follow rules for stackoverflow sorry again. I will read everything when I wake up tomorrow. It is night in here :(

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to make a return type int instead of T.
Because when you use binarySearch(...) the return type = std::string.

```
template <class T>
int binarySearch(T arr[], int left, int right, T x)
```

Comment: Yes I did. I have fixed to  int binarySearch(...) , but I cannot not get the string result

Comment: You need to get string result from initial array. Use returned index.

Comment: It works after I fixed if statement to `while(left <= right)` and delete else statement above `return -1`  Thanks!